Прошу помощи с решением задачи на питоне
В базе данных хранится список настоящих пользователей вашего сервиса, среди которых есть несколько тестовых. На первой строке программа получает полный список всех пользователей, а на второй – индексы тестовых пользователей в списке. Используя цикл for, напечатайте только имена настоящих пользователей в одну строку.
Sample Input 1:
Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dave, Eve  
1, 3  

Sample Output 1:
Alice Charlie Eve  

Sample Input 2:
Alice, Bob, Charlie  
0, 2  

Sample Output 2:
Bob  

Я решил так
full_list=input().split(", ") # full_list=['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave', 'Eve']
indexes=list(map(int, input().split(", "))) # indexes=[1, 3]
real_list=[]
for i, text in enumerate(full_list):
    if indexes[0]==i:
        continue
    if indexes[1]==i:
        continue
    real_list.append(text)    
print(*real_list)

В песочницах все хорошо, ответы правильные, а на образовательном курсе решение не проходит. Выдает
Failed test #3 of 3. Runtime error
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 8, in <module>
    if indexes[1]==i:
IndexError: list index out of range

Попробовал через while
full_list=input().split(", ")
a,b=list(map(int, input().split(", ")))
i=0
names_of_real_users=[]
while len(full_list)>i:
    names_of_real_users=full_list[i]
    i=i+1
    if names_of_real_users==full_list[a]:
        continue
    if names_of_real_users==full_list[b]:
        continue
    print(names_of_real_users, end=" ")

На это раз ошибка:
Failed test #3 of 3. Runtime error
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 3, in <module>
    a,b=list(map(int, input().split(", ")))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)


А если индексов 3 или 1?
#full_list=input().split(", ")
full_list=['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave', 'Eve']
#indexes=list(map(int, input().split(", ")))
indexes=[1, 3]
real_list=[]
for i,name_f in enumerate(full_list):
    if i in indexes:
        continue
    real_list.append(name_f)
print(*real_list)


Alice Charlie Eve

Спасибо @MBo  увидел мою ошибку

full_list.pop(i) при этом индексы не поплывут ли?

@MBo Да поплыли.

Можно индексы отсортировать и с больших к меньшим удалять. Или real_list=[name_f for i,name_f in enumerate(full_list) if not i in indexes]

Ребята, спасибо огромное! Решение засчитано.

А indexes лучше множеством сделать, быстрее проверки будут проходить, если индексов там много будет.

Да. спасибо. теперь дошло).

Почти всё сделано правильно. Осталось собрать индексы в множество и отфильтровать список:
users = input().split(', ')
indices = set(map(int, input().split(', ')))
print(*(name for i, name in enumerate(users) if i not in indices))


$ echo -e "Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dave, Eve\n1, 3" | python real-users.py
Alice Charlie Eve

$ echo -e "Alice, Bob, Charlie\n0, 2" | python real-users.py
Bob



Спасибо за лаконичный код!)
